# Error while installing Virtual box extension pack

Tags: virtualbox

I have downloaded Virtual box 7.0.6 (VirtualBox-7.0.6-155176-Linux_amd64.run) and its extension pack (Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.6.vbox-extpack) from Oracle's site. Installation of the program was smooth. Not so for the extension. I tried to install it via GUI (`File / Tools / Extension pack manager`) and from terminal. In both cases it gives me the following error:

```
cd /opt/VirtualBox/
sudo VBoxManage extpack install ./Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.6.vbox-extpack
...
0%...NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/opt/VirtualBox/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.6.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: World writable: '/opt'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" at line 1912 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

The path `/opt/VirtualBox/` is where the program was installed (I copied the extension pack overthere as well, just in case, after my attempts to install it from `home` failed with the same message).

My OS ist Lubuntu 20.04 64-bit. `/opt/` has the permissions `drwxrwxrwx` and is owned by `root`. So is `/opt/VirtualBox/`.

P. S. Surely, I tried to install it without `sudo`. It makes no difference.

P. P. S. I had read many threads with description of the same problem (it is curious that majority of them are rather old) before I posted here. The set of advices effectively reduces to «Use 'sudo'!».

Comment: The `error: World writable: '/opt'` message is a warning that `/opt` is `777`, which is a big no-no. You will want to correct those permissions, as a bunch of tools that use `/opt` will outright refuse to use a directory that can be written to by anything ...

Comment: @matigo That did it. I changed the permissions for /opt/ as well as /opt/VirtualBox/ directories to the default 755 and the extension managed to install without any issues. Thank you for your helping! Should you choose to convert your comment into an answer, I would be glad to accept it as the solution.